# Правильное обращение к БД, как реализовать?

Tags: php, mysql, оптимизация, кэширование

Вопрос думаю очень прост до безумия, но я совсем еще новичок и даже не знаю как правильно задать вопрос гуглу =)

Существует таблица в MySQL которая в будущем будет иметь Несколько Сотен Тысяч записей.
Эта таблица постоянно пополняется новыми записями.
Предположим запись имеет 2 значения: 1) Number 2) UserID

Нужно сложить весь столбик Number, где UserID = ID юзера сессии, после чего полученную цифру вывести на определенную страницу, например в профиль пользователя. Как это сделать мне понятно (хотя не факт что верно), я уже это реализовал выводом всех данных в массив, после чего циклом foreach складываю все числа. Проблема в том что при каждом обновлении страницы отправляется этот запрос. Но у меня сейчас всего 10-20 записей в таблице и я сижу 1 у себя на локалке, это делается мгновенно. А что же будет, если на сайте будет большой онлайн и они постоянно будут жать f5? ну явно ничего хорошего.

Собственно вопрос в том, как вообще все это правильно реализовать, что бы запрос не отправлялся при каждом обновлении страницы и не было проблем с перегрузкой.

Comment: Делайте на 1 юзера 1 запись обновляя значение в ней.

Comment: Этот вариант рассматривается конкретно для этой страницы. Но дело в том, что на дугой странице мне нужно будет выводить все эти цифры по отдельности, в виде истории. Простейший пример: история пополнения счета в личном кабинете. Там нужно вывести все записи с пополнениями, где UserID = ID Сессии.

Comment: Эту таблицу оставляете как есть для вывода истории, а в таблице юзеров добавляете поле в котором будет общий результат изменяемый при пополнении счета.

Comment: @z0diac Вообще что бы получить сумму в SQL было бы достаточно `select sum(Number) from table where userid=1` или количества по всем пользователям (по строке на каждого) `select userid, sum(Number) from table group by userid`. Это в разы быстрее любых foreach. Но конечно если эту цифру надо выдавать постоянно, то есть смысл сохранять ее готовую в пользователе